# Angular localization formControlName, the numbers in dot notation for thousands and decimal comma

Tags: angular

I have a field weight= 12000 I want format this in a input form 12.000,00 with 2 decimals and dot notation.

In view I have correctly using pipe and it works ok code:

```
<td>{{item.weight| number: '.2'}}</td>
```

I want the same result in input form but I can't format / localize :

```
<input type="number" formControlName="weight" class="form-control">
```

I can't apply pipe on input field with decimal and dot notation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

constructor(        
        private _decimal: DecimalPipe
    ) { }
```

and when you are patching value of your form:

```
weight: this._decimal.transform(this.item.weight, '1.2-2')
```